# MSCRM plugin. C# How to guarante single execution of critical block?

Tags: c#, locking, dynamics-crm

First of all, I'm facing strange issue in Microsoft Dynamics CRM Plugin code.

Here is my code example:

```
public class Counter : Plugin
{
    private static object Locker = new object();

    public Counter() : base(typeof(Counter)) 
    { 
        .... 
    }

    public void GenerateNumber(LocalPluginContext localContext)
    {
        IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;
        IPluginExecutionContext context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;

        Entity Target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

        var Number=0;
        lock(Locker)
        {
            var CounterEntity = service.GetCounterEntity();

            Number=(int)CounterEntity["number"];
            CounterEntity["number"]=Number+1;

            service.Update(CounterEntity);
        }

        Target["number"]=Number;
        service.Update(Entity);
    }
}
```

As I understand, each time some Entity is created, system creates instance of `Counter` and executes `GenerateNumber` method.
An instance of `Counter` should get last number from Counter Entity, increase it and save it to database.
But somehow, this code has generated same number twice.

If Counters created in different threads then `lock` should do his work.

Why this happened and how can i solve this problem?
Should I replace lock with semaphore?

Comment: service.Update(Entity); - Anyway, what do you mean by this? Is this explicit update of the same target entity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The platform does not create a new instance of your plugin every time it executes a plugin.  Per [the SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328263.aspx):

> For improved performance, Microsoft Dynamics 365 caches plug-in instances. The plug-in's Execute method should be written to be stateless because the constructor is not called for every invocation of the plug-in. Also, multiple system threads could execute the plug-in at the same time. All per invocation state information is stored in the context, **so you should not use global variables or attempt to store any data in member variables for use during the next plug-in invocation unless that data was obtained from the configuration parameter provided to the constructor**. Changes to a plug-ins registration will cause the plug-in to be re-initialized.

The problem you are trying to solve is very frequently incorrectly solved.  Many of the solutions posted online have the same issue you are facing where, when many records are created around the same time, duplicate auto-numbers are generated. My two favorite (and definitely correct) resources for understanding this issue are:

- [Scalable Customization Design in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45905) : After clicking download, choose the document called *ScalableDynamicsCRMCustomizations.docx*.  It is a white paper and therefore pretty long, but it explains the ins and outs of what you want to know.  In particular, see the section titled *Why it’s important to understand transactions: Auto numbering example*.
- [How to Implement Robust Auto-Numbering Using Transactions in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://www.greenbeacon.com/insights/how-to-implement-robust-auto-numbering-using-transactions-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm/): this is much shorter but covers the most important issues.  I found that I needed to fully understand the white paper in order to truly understand how the platform works.

Comment: The examples in the white paper are excellent. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to say is that CRM doesn't create an instance of your plugin every time that it's triggered, so you should keep that in mind at all times (all plugins s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ must be stateless):

> For improved performance, Microsoft Dynamics 365 caches plug-in
>   instances. The plug-in's Execute method should be written to be
>   stateless because the constructor is not called for every invocation
>   of the plug-in. Also, multiple system threads could execute the
>   plug-in at the same time. All per invocation state information is
>   stored in the context, so you should not use global variables or
>   attempt to store any data in member variables for use during the next
>   plug-in invocation unless that data was obtained from the
>   configuration parameter provided to the constructor. Changes to a
>   plug-ins registration will cause the plug-in to be re-initialized.

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328263.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

About how to implement an auto numbering solution locking the record (counter entity in your example), there is a really nice article that will help you:
[How to Implement Robust Auto-Numbering Using Transactions in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://www.greenbeacon.com/insights/how-to-implement-robust-auto-numbering-using-transactions-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm/)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have registered your plugin for the PreOperation stage of the Create message. That stage participates in the database transaction. However, a read operation on an autonumber entity does not lock the record it reads.

The trick is to first write a random value to a dummy field of the autonumber record. This will apply a lock on the record. Then read the number field, increment it and save the autonumber record.

Answer (score 0):

You may use context.depth which should be set to 1.

Comment: This may be the solution for OP title, but the accepted answer gave better solution for the problem explained in question.

Answer (score 0):

New version of CRM Dynamic support transaction. I have successed to index ID for record. Same with your counter. Document link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45905 (Transaction Control Page 12).